# How to convert array to object by key?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I got this array:

```
const users =[ 
   { 
      id:1,
      name:'bob',

   },
   { 
      id:2,
      name:'sally',

   },
   { 
      id:3,
      name:'bob',
      age:30,

   }
];
```

And I want to use any key(in this case 'name' ) to return an object :

```
{ 
   bob:[ 
      { 
         id:1,
         name:'bob',

      },
      { 
         id:3,
         name:'bob',
         age:30,

      }
   ],
   sally:[ 
      { 
         id:2,
         name:'sally',

      }
   ],
}
```

I tried this:

```
const go = (A,key) =>{
    return A.reduce((o, key) => ({ ...o, [key]:o }), {})
}

export default go;
```

But this returns:

```
{ '[object Object]': { '[object Object]': { '[object Object]': {} } } }
```

If the key is not present omit from the result. It should not mutate the original array though. How can I perform this kind of conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the approach you have, a new array is not instantiated in case the key is not yet present in the object.

This will work:

```
const result = users.reduce((a, v) => {
  a[v.name] = a[v.name] || [];
  a[v.name].push(v);
  return a;
}, {});
```

**Complete snippet wrapping this logic in a function:**

```js
const users = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'bob',

}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'sally',

}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'bob',
  age: 30,

}];

const go = (input, key) => input.reduce((a, v) => {
  a[v[key]] = a[v[key]] || [];
  a[v[key]].push(v);
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(go(users, 'name'));
```

---

If you really want to cram it into a one-liner, this will also work, by either spreading the already existing array, or an empty one:

```
const result = users.reduce((a, v) => ({...a, [v.name]: [...a[v.name] || [], v]}), {});
```

**Complete snippet wrapping this logic in a function:**

```js
const users = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'bob',

}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'sally',

}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'bob',
  age: 30,

}];

const go = (input, key) => input.reduce((a, v) => ({...a, [v[key]]: [...a[v[key]] || [], v]}), {});

console.log(go(users, 'name'));
```

Comment: This works only for the parameter 'name'. It does not if I input the parameter 'id'.

Comment: Just needs to be wrapped in a function that also accepts the property name.

Comment: I edited the snippets to wrap the logic in a function.

Comment: If I use the age parameter it returns the undefined array. How can I skip the objects that are undefined?

Comment: First filter out only those that have the property set: `input.filter(v => v.key != null).reduce(...)`

Comment: If I do that it returns an empty array.

Comment: I just tried the approach I suggested with my own snippet. Works perfectly fine. You probably need to update your question to provide further details about the output you expect if the key is not present.

Answer (score 0):

You were close but the `key` attribute in this case was each value (eg: `{ id: 1, name: 'bob' }`) so the string representation is `[object Object]` which is why all the keys are that. Based off what you said, you want to use `key.name` as the property and set it's value as `[key]`. (I renamed key to `arr` in my example since it's the array value).

So this would be something like `{ ...o, [arr.name]: [arr] }`

Because there can be an existing value, it adds a bit of complexity which is what `[...(obj[arr.name] || []), arr]` is doing. It's looking up the existing value (or defaulting to an empty array) and spreading those values and adding the new value.

```js
const users = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'bob',

  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'sally',

  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'bob',
    age: 30,

  }
];


const transform = (input, keyName) => {
  return input.reduce((obj, arr) => ({ ...obj,
    [arr[keyName]]: [...(obj[arr[keyName]] || []), arr]
  }), {})
}

console.log(transform(users, 'name'))
console.log(transform(users, 'id'))
```

Comment: This works only for the parameter 'name'. It does not if I input the parameter 'id'.

Comment: @bierhier ah I see what you were trying to do now. Got it. I updated the answer to handle a dynamic key.

Comment: if I use 'age' as a parameter I still get the undefined objects returned?

Comment: Because `bob` and `sally` do not have an `age`. So both of those are `undefined`. Try adding age to both of those.

Comment: I don't want to change the input.

Comment: Then since the `age` value is `undefined` that sounds correct? What else would it be put under? You didn't define the expected output if the key (`age`) is only in _some_ of the objects